# Trouble using a child class

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I am attenmpting to initialise an instance of a class from a base class, where the class to be used will be determined in a switch case, as follows:

ImportBase.cs: (Parent abstract class and interface)

```
namespace WebApi.Services.Import.Investments
{
    interface IImport
    {
        public void Import(IFormFile file, int UserId);
    }

    public abstract class ImportBase : IImport
    {
        public abstract void Import(IFormFile file, int UserId);

    }
}
```

ImportKuflink.cs (Child class)

```
namespace WebApi.Services.Import.Investments
{
    public class ImportKuflink : ImportBase
    {
        public override void Import(IFormFile file, int UserId)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Import Kuflink");
        }
    }
}
```

ImportFleet.cs (Child class)

```
namespace WebApi.Services.Import.Investments
{
    public class ImportFleet : ImportBase
    {
        public override void Import(IFormFile file, int UserId)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Import Fleet");
        }
    }
}
```

and in my controller:

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class InvestmentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        public void Import()
        {
            ImportBase importService = null;

            switch(investmentEntity)
            {
                case "kuflink":
                    ImportKuflink importService = new();
                    break;

                case "Fleet":
                    ImportFleet importService = new();
                    break;                    
            }

            if (importService != null)
            {
                importService.Import(file, UserId);
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to use the instance, I get the error "'importService' does not exist in the current context"

Is there a way I can test if importService was initialised and use it outside of the case statements?

I am basically have a base class and then a few other classes which will inherit from this class, and depending on the type of import occuring the appropriate child class will be used.  How can I go about this?

Comment: More detailed code example is needed. If you can post your code on github, I'll try to help.

Comment: Try switching your syntax around to: importService = new ImportKuflink();

Comment: `ImportKuflink importService = new();` declares and assigns a new block-local variable. It does _not_ assign your existing field `this.importService`. Both exist independently. But you also have to show where your `if` statement is located (same class, same method, etc.), otherwise it is impossible to answer. Your code does not compile currently, so providing an [mre] helps immensly to get others to answer the question.

Comment: More code has been added to the question.  As you can hopefully see, declaring importService as an instance of a specific class is not possible in my case as I need this to be determined in the case blocks, but IO should be able to use the instance of the child class outside thew switch statement.

Comment: Declare importService using the interface `IImport`, and then assign an instance to it like this: `importService = new ImportKuflink();` "Service" suggests it's intended as a DI service?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks, my importService is declared using IImport as you kindly suggested.  i wasn't sure if I should use Di here as the actual instance for the service class is only created within the switch statement (and not in a constructor as is usually the case with Di services)

Comment: If the different instances don't have dependencies themselves then your way is perfectly sound.  Your use of *Service* in the name prompted me to ask the question.  If you do have (or want) dependencies then there are ways to inject them.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message »'importService' does not exist in the current context« does not match your program and I doubt that the code as shown will show this error.

I assume that you are actually seeing a different error. Let's first reduce your code to the smallest possible program to exhibit the (a?) problem.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name:");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        Object importService = null;

        switch(input)
        {
            case "x":
                String importService = "";
                break; 
        }

        if (importService != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(importService);
        }        
    }
}
```

The scope/lifetime of a variable in C# is generally determined by its enclosing block. Declaring a variable (with `TypeName variableName`) makes this variable visible inside its block. When execution exits the block, the variable is no longer accessible.

Assigning a variable is done with the assignment operator (i.e. `=`), but without specifying the type name, e.g. `variableName = value`.

Blocks are opened with `{` and closed with `}`. Blocks can be (arbitrarily) nested. Variables in inner blocks shadow variables of the outer blocks. Variables of outer blocks are accessible in inner blocks, unless shadowed.

When you declare a variable in an inner block with a name identical to an existing variable in an outer block, the variable of the outer block becomes inaccessible to the current block and any of its descendants.

In the example, you have 4 relevant blocks:

1. The class
2. The method
3. The switch statement
4. The if statement

The method declares a variable `importService` and immediately assigns it the value `null`: `Object importService = null`. The declaration and assignment could be split, to make it more explicit:

```
Object importService; // declaration
importService = null; // assignment
```

The switch statement opens a new block, and this block declares a new and *independent* variable, which shadows the variable of the outer block (the method): `String importService`. Once the outer variable is shadowed, it cannot be accessed from within the inner block. Assigning the inner variable has no effect on the shadowed variable.

In other words: the switch statement declares and assigns a new variable of type `String` and name `importService`, then does *nothing* with it. Once the switch statement is exited, the variable is gone and no longer accessible.

After leaving the switch statement's block, the shadowed variable (`importService` of type `Object`) becomes accessible again. But nothing happened with this variable, its value is still `null` – remember: variables with identical name in nested blocks are distinct and independent.

What do you need to do to "fix" your program? Don't declare a new variable with the same name, but instead assign the original variable. This was already mentioned in the [comments under the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75044190/trouble-using-a-child-class#comment132430371_75044190):

> `ImportKuflink importService = new();` declares and assigns a new block-local variable. It does not assign your existing field this.importService. Both exist independently. […]

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name:");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        Object importService = null;

        switch(input)
        {
            case "x":
                importService = ""; // assign, don't redeclare!
                break; 
        }

        if (importService != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(importService);
        }        
    }
}
```